# Does it make sense to index a core data attribute of type date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, indexing

Since a core data model attribute of type date contains date and time, does it make any sense to make it indexed?  In other database environments, I thought it was good practice to not index attributes with too few or too many unique values.

In my particular case, the vast majority of dates will be nil.  My predicate looks like this:

```
NSPredicate *subPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xDate == nil || xDate < %@", [NSDate date]];
```

Currently my xDate field is not indexed and a typical fetch takes about 2.4 seconds which is way too long IMO for only 1300 returned records.

Comment: @Ian, I did but seem to get inconsistent benchmarks.  I also don't know what the impact is on index size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion after hours of debugging and analyzing that you just can't make core data use an index if it determines there's a better way.

This [blog post](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/01/optimizing-core-data-searches-and-sorts/) helped me understand how to use SQLite’s `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` to analyze the strategy used to execute the fetch.

Basically, what I did was:

In Xcode:

- Set `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` in my run scheme
- Logged my .sqlite database location after I setup the persistant store.  I did this because the iOS 8 simulator path changes with each install.

In Terminal:

- Open Terminal and execute `/usr/bin/sqlite3`
- From the sqlite>  prompt I issued an `.open` command with the path of the database I previously logged to the debugger console.  I did it this way because I have multiple persistant stores.
- From the sqlite> prompt I performed `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` with the SQL select statment that com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug logged to the debugger console.

You can also issue the `.indices` command to sqlite3 to verify your indexes are as expected.

Obviously, this only works in the simulator since you can't open a database on the device from Terminal.

To make things even easier moving between multiple datastores and simulator locations I call this method after setting up the persistant store:

```
- (void)examineQuery
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    [result appendString: @"\n/usr/bin/sqlite3"];
    [result appendFormat: @"\n.open '%@'", [self.coreDataStack.databaseURL path]];
    [result appendString: @"\nEXPLAIN QUERY PLAN "];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

I just copy all 3 lines from the debugger and paste them into Terminal.  Then I find the logged `SELECT` statement in the debugger, copy and paste it into Terminal.  You'll need to type a `;` at the end of the completed `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` command in order for sqlite3 to terminate input and process the command.

In my case sqlite3 `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` gave this result:

```
SCAN TABLE ZART AS t0 USING INDEX ZART_ZNAME_INDEX
```

Okay, it's using a different index. Taking a look my NSFetchRequest I can now assume that the sort descriptor is determining the index.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:kEntityName];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)],
                           nil];
```

I changed my code to guarantee the xDate was never NULL to determine if the OR clause was causing core data to not use my index on xDate.  I was now able to make xDate not optional in the model and changed my predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xDate > %@", [NSDate date]]
```

sqlite3 `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` gave the same result:

```
SCAN TABLE ZART AS t0 USING INDEX ZART_ZNAME_INDEX
```

The last thing I tried was creating a compound index on xDate,name.  Going through the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` process again yielded the same result.

During my investigation I came across multiple references to core data optimizing fetches with no guarantees about index usage. I'm assuming that's the wall I've hit.

Oddly, my fetches are now down to .21 seconds even though the xDate and xDate,name indices aren't being used.  I believe the improvement came from deleting my app from the simulator and doing a fresh install.  All my index usage tests were done after the fresh app install (before you ask ;)

It appears that adding indicies to my model didn't propagate to the already installed database. I did try migrating to a new version of the database first but it still didn't seem to add new indicies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely fastens the query results. I have tried it.

I had a large data, where the result were -
Without indexing ~ 2 seconds
With indexing ~ .2 - .3 seconds

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I'm definitely not seeing measurable differences.  Wonder if it's the the OR in the predicate.  Core data generates a SQL where clause: WHERE (  t0.ZXDATE IS NULL OR  t0.ZXDATE < ?)